# rabl reusing a template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I have this `show.json.rabl` for the show action of a controller to render out some JSON in my Rails app, I figure that the `edit` action's JSON response is no different than my show one, so I wonder if there is a method to use the `show.json.rabl` for the `edit` action.

I know that I can use "extend `users/show` in my `edit.json.rabl`, but what if I want to get rid of `edit.json.rabl` altogether and have a line in the controller that specifies that this action's json response should use show action's rabl template. Can this be done?

Thank you

Comment: Can you try to add `render :show` in your `def edit` for your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way, but you can render the JSON directly with Rabl

```
render :inline => Rabl::Renderer.json(@user, 'users/show')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rabl >= '0.11.6', you would have to provide the view_path parameter (that is if it is not already set globally in your rabl.rb config file) like so:

```
render :inline => Rabl::Renderer.json(@user, 'users/show', :view_path => 'app/views')
```

else you would get the following error:

```
RuntimeError (Cannot find rabl template 'users/show' within registered ([]) view paths!):
```